# How can I prove $\arctan \left( nx \right)$ isn't convergent over $C\left[ 0,1 \right]$ with respect to distance $\max$

Tags: functional-analysis

The problem is to prove that $\arctan \left( nx \right)$ is not convergent over $C\left[ 0,1 \right]$ with respect to distance $d=\underset{x\in \left[ a,b \right]}{\max}\left| f\left( x \right) -g\left( x \right) \right|$.

I know I have to prove that $d\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, but I don't know how to do that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you been able to determine the pointwise limit function? The question is whether the sequence converges uniformly to that limit function.

Comment: @Gary I know that $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathrm{arc}\tan \left( nx \right) =\frac{\pi}{2}$ on $\left( 0,\infty \right)$. But clearly it's not true on $\left[ 0,1 \right]$.

Comment: Note that the limit function $f(x)$ takes the value $0$ at $x=0$ and $\pi/2$ on $(0,1]$. For each $n\geq 1$, we have $\max _{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \left| {f(x) - \arctan (nx)} \right| \ge \left| {f\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) - \arctan (n\frac{1}{n})} \right| = \frac{\pi }{4}$. Can you conclude?

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I don't quite understand why the inequility holds true. For $x<\frac{1}{n}$, should it be $\max _{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \left| {f(x) - \arctan (nx)} \right| \le \left| {f\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) - \arctan (n\frac{1}{n})} \right|$?

Comment: You taken the maximum of that quantity over the whole interval with respect to $x$. $x$ is a dummy variable. The left-hand side of the inequality does not depend on $x$, the maximum is a concrete number.

Comment: How silly I am :(. Thanks again!